# What is the boost equivalent to std::optional nullopt?

Tags: c++, boost

I've imported some code pieces from a third party project into my C++11 project. The third party project uses optional-lite [1], though I'm using Boost heavily in the project and want to keep dependency on other libraries low.

There is `boost::optional`, but unlike the c++17 counterpart it does not have `nullopt`.

What's the Boost equivalent to `nullopt`?

(Note: Boost version is 1.69)

[1] https://github.com/martinmoene/optional-lite

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The boost equivalent of `std::nullopt` is [`boost::none`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference.html). See [`optional(none_t)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_constructor_none_t).